# Hitboxes of targets (Breakout)

Tags: javafx

I got a JavaFX programm and I am not sure how I get the values to determine when the ball hits the target bricks, which are created in two for loops. I got my ball already moving on its own, but I do not have the hitbox of my paddle yet nor my targets. I would like to hear your ideas or startegies to make that work. Thanks for reading!

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class Breakout extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static final int width = 700;
    private static final int height = 900;
    private boolean gameStarted;
    private int rad = 10;
    private int ballYPos = width / 2;
    private int ballXPos = height / 2;
    private int paddleXpos = width / 2;
    private int paddleYpos = height - 100;
    private int ballXSpeed = 2;
    private int ballYSpeed = 2;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(width, height);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        Timeline t = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), e -> run(gc)));
        t.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        canvas.setOnMouseClicked(e -> gameStarted = true);
        //Kanvas mit KeyHandler, den ich verwenden möchte
        canvas.setOnKeyPressed(e -> paddleXpos--);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Breakout");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(canvas)));
        primaryStage.show();
        t.play();
    }

    public void run(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.setFill(Color.GRAY);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        gc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        gc.fillOval(ballXPos, ballYPos, rad, rad);
        gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        gc.fillRect(paddleXpos, paddleYpos, 50, 10);
        gc.setFill(Color.RED);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                gc.fillRect(j * 130 + 55, i * 30 + 40, 75, 20);
            }
        }
        if (gameStarted) {
            ballYPos += ballYSpeed;
            ballXPos += ballXSpeed;
            if (ballXPos == width - rad || ballXPos == 0) {
                ballXSpeed *= -1;
            }
            if (ballYPos == height - rad || ballYPos == 0) {
                ballYSpeed *= -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how about doing a bit of research - you are not the first to write a game like that, there are tons of examples :)

Comment: I know I am not the only one with that problem, but it is quite difficutl to understand the others thoughtprocess on it and then to edit the code of their results into mine

Comment: practice helps, no way around to at least try :) Do some research, apply what you learned, when stuck come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected (vs. an example that's unrelated to your problem ..)

Comment: According to [this](https://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/2019/12/some-fun-with-javafx-canvas-spacefx.html), you should keep up the with coordinates of all your objects. Use math to determine when there is a collision. Look for `check for bigTorpedo hits`, `check for rocket hits`, and/or `check for torpedo hits` from [here](https://github.com/HanSolo/SpaceFX/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/hansolo/spacefx/SpaceFXView.java). I hope this helps!